# Find all distributive latices with 5 elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I believe that in order for a lettuce to be distributive, all its sublettices must be non isomorphic with M5 and N5 but I don't know how to prove that. Or if there is a different way.

Comment: Check [this book](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf), page 12.

Comment: Maybe [this][1]https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Distributive_lattice